# Delegação de eventos a elementos gerados dinamicamente

Tags: jquery, html, json, classificação

Vou tentar ser mais específico. Possuo uma lista `<ul>`que é populada via jQuery:

```
var $imovel  = $("#lista-resultados-pesquisa");


$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'imovel.json',
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.imovel,function(i, imovel){
        $imovel.append('<li value="'+ imovel.preco +'">Meu conteudo</li>');
    })
  }
});
```

Pelo fato de os itens da minha lista não estarem no html, não consigo manipula-los... Por exemplo, preciso ordenar minha lista de acordo com o atributo `value` das tags `<li>`, e também preciso ter um botão `loadMore` para limitar a quantidade de elementos que aparece na tela. Ja tenho isso, o problema é que não consigo manipular os itens da minha lista "`<li>`" que estão sendo inseridos dinâmicamente, por assim dizer, oriundos do meu arquivo json local.

Vou mostrar as funcões para ordenação e loadMore que tenho comigo.

```
//LOADMORE
            var size_li = $("#lista-resultados-pesquisa .intens-pesquisa").size();
            var x=3;
            $("#lista-resultados-pesquisa .intens-pesquisa:lt("+x+")").show();
            $("#loadMore").click(function () {
                x= (x+3 <= size_li) ? x+3 : size_li;
                $("#lista-resultados-pesquisa .intens-pesquisa:lt("+x+")").show();
                if(x == size_li){
                    $("#loadMore").hide();
                }
            });     

            //ORDENA
                $('.ordena-menor').click(function() {
                  $("#lista-resultados-pesquisa .itens-pesquisa").sort(numOrdDesc).appendTo('#lista-resultados-pesquisa');
                });

                $('.ordena-maior').click(function() {
                  $("#lista-resultados-pesquisa .itens-pesquisa").sort(numOrdCres).appendTo('#lista-resultados-pesquisa');
                });


                function numOrdDesc(a, b) {
                  return ($(b).val()) < ($(a).val()) ? 1 : -1;
                }

                function numOrdCres(a, b) {
                  return ($(b).val()) > ($(a).val()) ? 1 : -1;
                }
```

Valeu Gurizada, um forte abraço e um ótimo final de semana a todos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delega o evento ao elemento pai, a um elemento em que se consiga associar o evento logo no carregamento da página. Em vez de delegares ao elemento em especifico que ainda não existe. Para delegares eventos a elementos gerados dinamicamente, neste caso, os `li` dentro de `#lista-resultados-pesquisa` faz assim:

```
$("#lista-resultados-pesquisa").on('click', 'li', function(){
   ...
});
```

Fiz aqui um [EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/0hbeftgo/1/), como está funciona, descomenta o evento click em baixo, e tira o de cima para veres que delegando o evento diretamente no elemento não funciona

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   $('#lista-resultados-pesquisa').append('<li>clica aqui: ' +i+ '</li>');
  }
});

// tira isto
$('#lista-resultados-pesquisa').on('click', 'li', function(){
alert('Isto resulta');
});

// e coloca isto para veres o que acontece/que não acontece
/*$('#lista-resultados-pesquisa li').click(function(){
alert('isto não resulta');
});*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lista-resultados-pesquisa">

</ul>
<button>
adicionar elementos gerados dinamicamente
</button>
```

Comment: Miguel, você me ajudou muito! Muito obrigado... No caso da função de LoadMore, não estou conseguindo aplicar. Sabes como utilizar o on() ao invés de ready()? Grande abraço!

Comment: De nada. Qual ready? Não vejo

Comment: Consegui meu caro amigo... Você foi de suma importancia para o sucesso! Obrigado!

Comment: De nada @JoãoSouza