# jquery blur em inputs dinamicos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário onde crio dinamicamente os `<inputs>`

Com a seguinte estrutura:

```
<input class="form-control placaCss Tamanho200 text-box single-line valid" id="Veiculos_3b875035-ae1b-4b69-8ddc-462bbfd86fbd__Placa" name="Veiculos[3b875035-ae1b-4b69-8ddc-462bbfd86fbd].Placa" type="text" value="" aria-invalid="false">

<input class="form-control text-box single-line veiculo" id="Veiculos_4aa0f9aa-cbbf-4b3a-9a39-de41bed5f773__MarcaModelo" name="Veiculos[4aa0f9aa-cbbf-4b3a-9a39-de41bed5f773].MarcaModelo" type="text" value="">
```

Veja que no ID é injetado um Guid no qual não tenho controle.

O que eu gostaria de fazer é que quando terminar de digitar a placa ele execute minha função javascript que terá um ajax. Mas somente para o input digitado, ex: se tiver 3 apenas é executado no input digitado.

Consegui fazer via Style que criei chamado placaCss porém funciona de forma errada, pois ele até é chamado para cada input mas altera todos os outros

Meu código:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
              $('.placaCss').blur('input', function () {

                  if ($(this).val() != "")
                  {
                   $('.Veiculo').val('teste');
                       alert($(this).val());
                  }
              });
          });
```

Rodando no fiddle
https://fiddle.jshell.net/nmcpjpss/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que é isso que precisa

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.placaCss').blur('input', function() {
    var valor = $(this).val();
    var _this = $(this);
    // Verificando se o valor foi preenchido
    if (valor) {
      var proVeiculo = _this.nextAll('.veiculo:first');
      proVeiculo.val(valor);
      alert(valor);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Placas: <input class="form-control placaCss Tamanho200 text-box single-line valid" id="Veiculos_3b875035-ae1b-4b69-8ddc-462bbfd86fbd__Placa" name="Veiculos[3b875035-ae1b-4b69-8ddc-462bbfd86fbd].Placa" type="text" value="" aria-invalid="false">
<br> Modelo:
<input class="form-control text-box single-line veiculo" id="Veiculos_4aa0f9aa-cbbf-4b3a-9a39-de41bed5f773__MarcaModelo" name="Veiculos[4aa0f9aa-cbbf-4b3a-9a39-de41bed5f773].MarcaModelo" type="text" value="">
<hr> Placas: <input class="form-control placaCss Tamanho200 text-box single-line valid" id="Veiculos_3b875035-ae1b-4b69-8ddc-462bbfd86fbd__Placa" name="Veiculos[b69-8ddc-462bbfd86fbd].Placa" type="text" value="" aria-invalid="false">
<br> Modelo:

<input class="form-control text-box single-line veiculo" id="Veiculos_-cbbf-4b3a-9a39-de41bed5f773__MarcaModelo" name="Veiculos[4aa0f9aa-cbbf-4b3a-9a39-de41bed5f773].MarcaModelo" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta [**delegação de eventos**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/132282/delega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-eventos-a-elementos-gerados-dinamicamente):

```
$( function () {
    $( ".placaCss" ).on( "blur", function () {
        var valor = $(this).val();
        if ( $(this).val() !== "" ) {
            alert( valor );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: boa noite..rs fiz um edit na minha pergunta até com exemplo no fidler, mas vou testar o seu código, vlw