# jquery n.fn.init(0) em produção em teste n.fn.init(1)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário que crio os campos input dinamicamente (ASP.NET MVC C#), quando o usuário digitar em um campo, desejo executar um ajax para preencher os outros campos.

Quando criei um teste.html, com os campos fixos e não sendo criado dinamicamente, funciona tudo!

Como visto em:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/nmcpjpss/3/
basicamente é o seguinte código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.placaCss').blur('input', function() {
    var valor = $(this).val();
    var _this = $(this);  //Esta linha retorna n.fn.init(1)
    // Verificando se o valor foi preenchido
    if (valor) {
        var proModelo = _this.nextAll('input.marcaModeloCss:first');
        proModelo.val(valor); 
    }
  });
});
```

Ao debugar no Chrome, percebo que o `_this` retorna `n.fn.init(1)` o que acredito que significa que ele encontrou o campo. por isso funciona.

Porém quando executo no meu formulário criado dinamicamente, ele me retorna
n.fn.init(0), acredito que nesse momento o jquery não encontrou na árvore DOM o meu objeto.
Porque no teste ele sobe o objeto pro DOM e no formulário dinamico não?

**Existe alguma forma de eu fazer o que estou querendo?**

testei também com outros formatos, mas todos retornam o campo errado no formulário dinamico e correto no teste.

```
var t1 = _this.nextAll('.marcaModeloCss:first');
var t2 = _this.nextAll('.marcaModeloCss').first();
var t3 = _this.nextUntil().last().next();
```

Minha pergunta original:
[jquery blur em inputs dinamicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226911/jquery-blur-em-inputs-dinamicos/226920#226920)

Encontrei uma pergunta semelhante e ele confirma que o erro é pq o seletor não foi encontrado no DOM
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494873/why-is-my-jquery-selector-returning-a-n-fn-init0-and-what-is-it
porém não explica uma possível solução.

---

Update:
Conforme sugestão fiz o recarregamento do blur, porém mesmo erro, para deixar mais claro o erro no formulário dinâmico, segue as imagens:

**Teste.html (funciona)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Formulário Dinâmico (errado)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Resposta final

Após ajuda dos posts abaixo, tive que fazer uma solução hibrida entre Jquery e Javascript puro.
Não ficou da forma mais elegante, mas infelizmente foi a única que funcionou, utilizando o jquery com .nextall não funcionou de nenhuma forma.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('blur', 'input.placaCss', function () {
            var valor = $(this).val();
            var _this = $(this);
            // Verificando se o valor foi preenchido
            if (valor) {
                var campo= document.getElementsByClassName('MarcaModelo');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/ConsultaVeiculo/Placa?placa=" + valor,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        campo[0].value = data.content.bin.marca;
                        campo[1].value = data.content.bin.ano_fabricacao;
                        campo[2].value = data.content.bin.ano_modelo;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
   });
```

resumindo, tive que buscar o css por `document.getElementsByClassName` que me retorna um array e assim trabalhar com o campo desejado.

Comment: Mostra o código de quando cria os inputs dinamicamente, provavelmente o erro está lá.

Comment: não entendi?, eu copiei o html gerado para o meu teste e funcionou, o html está no link fiddler

Comment: gostaria de quem colocou -1 pudesse me orientar pq essa pergunta não faz parte do scopo do site? visto que a pergunta americana tem up.

Comment: calma colega rs, a linha `var proModelo = _this.nextAll('input.marcaModeloCss:first');` tinha que retornar o próximo input desses, no fiddle lá funcionou, será que no seu HTML eles não são irmãos? Sobre o `document.getElementsByClassName`, usando como está você está sempre alterando os 3 primeiros do documento, não necessariamente os com relação ao input que você pegou o valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você conecta o elemento no evento `blur`, usando o método `blur()`, ele busca na página naquele momento os seletores e anexa diretamente a função handler. Se após isso você insere os novos campos do formulário, o handler não será chamado pois não está anexado ao novo elemento.

Para contornar isso, use o método `on` para delegar os eventos, no seguinte formato:

```
$(document).on('blur', 'input.placaCss', function() {...});
```

Desse modo, o evento não é chamado diretamente no elemento com classe `placacss`, mas sim nos descendentes de `document` que são `input` e possuem a classe `placaCss`, que é o que o seletor nesse caso diz.

Esse modo de anexar os eventos é chamado de delegated events.

Outra coisa, ao usar `$('.placaCss').blur('input', function() {...})`, você está passando a string `input` como dado, e não um seletor, como pode observar na documentação do método `blur` mais abaixo.

**Fontes:**

- https://api.jquery.com/on/
- https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: $('.placaCss').on('blur', 'input', function () {
nem executa a função...

Comment: Agora pude olhar o seu HTML e entendi como está a estrutura, já fiz o ajuste, conforme o David também indicou.

Comment: agora rodou, mas ainda estou com o erro que é do meu anunciado o var proModelo = _this.nextAll('input.marcaModeloCss:first'); não encontra o campo, ele fica com o mesmo valor de _this

Comment: Eles não são do mesmo valor. A string `n.fn.init(1)` indica que há um elemento no objeto jQuery que retornou, se você imprimir ele no console, verá que cada um deles é um objeto diferente.

Comment: é mas no caso está n.fn.init(0) ou seja ele não acha! _this.nextAll('input.marcaModeloCss:first'); não acha quando é dinamico

Comment: Estranho... você viu que anexei o evento em document, fez isso também? Criei um fork do seu jsfiddle e funcionou corretamente para os adicionados dinamicamente: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ya2ng9of/5/

Answer (score 2):

Realmente como amigo falou na outra resposta, é melhor usar o `.delegate()`. Basta alterar seu código original:

**De:**

```
$('.placaCss').blur('input', function() {
```

**Para:**

```
$(document).delegate('.placaCss','blur', function() {
```

Comment: Valeu David, porém não deu certo, veja as novas imagens que postei com o seu código.

Comment: Faltou chamar a função `aplica()` após o retorno do Ajax.

Comment: Deixa seu código como estava e aplique a alteração acima em apenas 1 linha do código.

Comment: Só uma observação, `delegate()` está "deprecated", é recomendado usar o `on()` segundo a documentação: https://api.jquery.com/delegate/